# How to change width of button when application is not fullscreen?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm making an application with JavaFX and Scene Builder.

I have Main class and controller that is called from main class.

I have a button in the controller  that has width - 45 and height - 90

Toggle button is wrapped in StackPane and StackPane is wrapped in AnchorPane

**How can I change buttonPrefWidth to 25 when application is *not* fullscreen and change button's prefWidth again to 45 when application *is* fullscreen?**

**Or can I change prefWidth of a button according to size of application?**

**Main Class:**

```
  public class Main extends Application {      

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  launch(args); 
 }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

  try {

  Parent root = 
 FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/card/resources/fxml/card.fxml"));
  Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1600, 600);
  primaryStage.setScene(scene);


  scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css")
  .toExternalForm());
  primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
  primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
  primaryStage.setResizable(true);

  primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("card/resources/logo-icon.png"));
  primaryStage.show();

    //adding resize and drag primary stage
    ResizeHelper.addResizeListener(primaryStage);

  //assign ALT+ENTER to maximize window
  final KeyCombination kb = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ENTER, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
  scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
      if (kb.match(event)) {
        primaryStage.setMaximized(!primaryStage.isMaximized());
        primaryStage.setResizable(true);

      }
    }
  });

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

}

}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

@FXML  private AnchorPane anchorRow;
@FXML  private StackPane hBoxCat0;
@FXML  private Button btnPalette;

@FXML
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

 }
}
```

**EDIT:**

@Slaw it doesn't work

[image: Errors]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the `prefWidth` between two numbers based on whether or not the window is full screen, then you can listen to the [`fullScreen` property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#fullScreenProperty()) of the `Stage` the `Button` belongs to.

```
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Controller {

  @FXML private Button btnPallet;

  @FXML
  private void initialize() {
    btnPallet.prefWidthProperty().bind(
        Bindings.when(Bindings.selectBoolean(btnPallet.sceneProperty(), "window", "fullScreen"))
            .then(45)
            .otherwise(25)
    );
  }

}
```

This will give you warnings at first since the `Button` won't be part of a `Scene` or `Window` at this point of the application. While these warnings are annoying the code should still work.